# Override org mode source block header args

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have this on top of the org file `#+property: header-args :results silent`, so this applies to the whole file. I can't override this within the source block:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results value :tangle no
(print org-attach-directory)
#+end_src
```

This just prints to the minibuffer. It works if I set the results to value in the properties drawer of the current heading but not as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `:results silent` header by using `:results replace` on the source code block (`replace` is the default):

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :results silent

#+begin_src elisp :results replace value
  (+ 3 4)

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 7
```

As you can see, the `:results` header may have multiple values attached. See [Results of Evaluation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html) in the manual. You can supply one value for each class of options: the classes are `Collection`, `Type`, `Format`, `Handling`, so you can have up to four values, e.g. you can say `:results value table drawer replace` where `value` is one of the allowed `Collection` values, `table is one of the allowed` Type`values, etc. There are additional wrinkles described in the manual, e.g. if the`Type`value is`file`, you may provide an additional` file: foo.ext` header to specify the file name where the results are going to be saved.

Or you can deactivate the property by adding a space after the `#+`

```
#+ PROPERTY: header-args :results silent
```

but you need to let Org mode know that you have done that. If you have another keyword (e.g. `#+TITLE: foo`) in the file, you can press `C-c C-c` on that: Org will reinitialize the mode and, in the process, deactivate the property. If the property is the only keyword in the file and you don't want to add another one, I know of nothing simpler than reinitializing the mode manually: `M-x normal-mode` is one way, closing and reopening the file is another.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realise that the results keyword has two parts in it; just re-read the docs. So, in the source block it should be `:results value replace`.

Comment: That's right: I added a paragraph with a link to the manual and some additional explanations.